# How can z index set in child of child view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

- LinerLayout

  - Frame layout 1

    - Relative layout 2

      - Imageview
      - Button
  - Relative layout 3

> I want set Button top of Frame layout 1 on Runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
LinerLayout
   Frame layout 1
     Relative layout 2
      Imageview
      Button
   Relative layout 3
```

**Change this layout to above layout.**